# ¿Como puedo cojer datos de un json en java?

Tags: java, json, gson

Tengo un problema y es que me he quedado estancado en esta parte en la cual a partir de un fichero json que tengo , tengo que cojer dentro del json en Java el name de un Pokemon en este caso y no entiendo como lo puedo hacer

Me podriais ayudar porfa , Os paso el codigo de lo que tengo

```
package AC3;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Pokemon {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public void generarPokemon()  {
        String json= "";
        try{
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\josep_gqq8b3l\\IdeaProjects\\DPO2223\\src\\AC3\\pokemon.json"));

            String linea= "";

            while ((linea= br.readLine())!= null){
                json+=linea;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Pokemon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
        
    }
}
 {
      "id": 144,
      "name": "Articuno",
      "description": "This Pokémon can control ice at will. Articuno is said to live in snowy mountains riddled with permafrost.",
      "sprite": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/144.png",
      "types": [
        "Ice",
        "Flying"
      ],
      "catchRate": 253,
      "fleeRate": 31.67
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu clase `Pokemon` debes declarar una propiedad por cada valor que haya en el JSON, con sus respectivos *getter* y *setter*.

Si el JSON se presenta así:

```
{
   "id":144,
   "name":"Articuno",
   "description":"This Pokémon can control ice at will. Articuno is said to live in snowy mountains riddled with permafrost.",
   "sprite":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/144.png",
   "types":[
      "Ice",
      "Flying"
   ],
   "catchRate":253,
   "fleeRate":31.67
}
```

Tu POJO debería quedar así:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Pokemon {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("sprite")
    @Expose
    private String sprite;

    @SerializedName("types")
    @Expose
    private List<String> types = null;

    @SerializedName("catchRate")
    @Expose
    private Integer catchRate;

    @SerializedName("fleeRate")
    @Expose
    private Double fleeRate;
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getSprite() {
        return sprite;
    }
    
    public void setSprite(String sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }
    
    public List<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }
    
    public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
    
    public Integer getCatchRate() {
        return catchRate;
    }
    
    public void setCatchRate(Integer catchRate) {
        this.catchRate = catchRate;
    }
    
    public Double getFleeRate() {
        return fleeRate;
    }
    
    public void setFleeRate(Double fleeRate) {
        this.fleeRate = fleeRate;
    }

}
```

NÓTESE que aquí no se comete el gravísimo error de meter una propiedad `Gson gson = new Gson();` dentro del POJO. Eso no tien ningún sentido. El objeto Gson se obtendrá siempre desde fuera del POJO y se mapeará a instancias del mismo. Si metes a Gson dentro del POJO estás capando a tu clase POJO. Lo mismo ocurre con el método `generarPokemon()`, el cual no debería ir nunca dentro del POJO. Debes pensar tu POJO como un molde para construir / mapear objetos de ese tipo desde diferentes contextos: un JSON, una base de datos, un XML, etc.

Ahora, si tuvieras varios `Pokemon` en tu JSON, puedes hacer algo como esto, en el contexto donde obtienes el JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
String fileName="C:\\Users\\josep_gqq8b3l\\IdeaProjects\\DPO2223\\src\\AC3\\pokemon.json";
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));

Pokemon[] pokemonArray = gson.fromJson(reader, Pokemon[].class);
```

`pokemonArray` será un array de instancias `Pokemon` que podrás usar para lo que necesites.

Si en el archivo tienes un sólo objeto, el código quedaría así:

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
String fileName="C:\\Users\\josep_gqq8b3l\\IdeaProjects\\DPO2223\\src\\AC3\\pokemon.json";
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));

Pokemon onePokemon = gson.fromJson(reader, Pokemon.class);
```

`onePokemon` sería una instancia de `Pokemon` con sus datos.

Es importante que quede claro, si quieres evitar confusiones en un futuro, que una cosa es el contexto donde obtienes los datos y otra cosa es tu modelo de datos. No metas nunca reglas de negocio en tu modelo de datos (como ha sido declarar el método `generarPokemon()` dentro de la clase `Pokemon`), o pronto estarás perdido en tu propio código.

¿Por qué? Porque como dije antes, tus datos en algunos contextos pueden venir de un JSON, pero en otros pueden venir de una Base de Datos, de un XML, etc y tu clase del modelo debería servir para mapear objetos sin importar el contexto, por eso no tiene sentido meter ese método ahí.

Además, puede haber contextos en que recibas una lista de objetos, otros un objeto simple, como se ha mostrado en los ejemplos. No tendría sentido que toda esa lógica (que es parte de las reglas de negocio) vaya en la clase del modelo de datos.

Finalmente, para ayudar a diseñar cómo debe ser tu clase cuando trabajas con datos estructurados (JSON u otros) te dejo [este enlace](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org). Allí puedes pegar tu contenido, y te generará la clase según los datos que haya en él. Puedes indicar también la herramienta con la que trabajarás, para que te genere las anotaciones.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Me ha servido:)